# Multiplying in between for matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> If I have $n \times n$ matrices, $A, P$, invertible and vector $v$

If I have something like:

$P^{-1}A v = \lambda P^{-1} v$, can I multiply in between the matrices?

$P^{-1}A$**P**$v$ = $\lambda P^{-1}$ **P** $v$

Can I multiply by $P$ in between?

Comment: If the vector $v$ is the same on the both sides, what does that say about the $\mathbf{U} = P^{-1}A$? The question of what happens to putting a matrix in between two matrices is different from what you are asking, i.e., if $AB$ = $CD$, does that mean that $AEB = CED$?

Answer (score 1):

$P^{-1}Av = \lambda P^{-1}v$ is only true of $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$. If $\mathbf{P}$ is supposed to be another matrix, it is not generally true that $P^{-1}A\mathbf{P}v = \lambda P^{-1}\mathbf{P}v$ if the first condition holds.

Answer (score 1):

from $P^{-1}Av=\lambda P^{-1}v=P^{-1}(\lambda v) $ we have, left multiplying both sides by $P$, $Av=\lambda v$ so $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ for the eigenvalue $\lambda$.

$P^{-1}AP$ is a matrix symilar to $A$ so it has the same eigenvectors and eigenvalues and we have:
$$
(P^{-1}AP)v=\lambda v \; \iff \; (P^{-1}AP)v=\lambda Iv \; \iff \; (P^{-1}AP)v=\lambda (P^{-1}P)v
$$

Answer (score 1):

There should be some constrains to $\mathbf{A}$, $\lambda$ and $v$ or your first equation will not be true. Such as $\lambda$ is eigenvalue of $\mathbf{A}$ and $v$ is the corresponding eigenvector $\mathbf{A}$. Or you cannot multiply the matrix.